# A file with the name User always saves as a text file in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am working on a Spring Boot application. I need a Java class named `User`. Ever since I created it as a class in IntelliJ, the file has been saved as a text file. I have deleted the file and made new Java classes with other names. The files with other names save as a Java class, but whenever I name it `User`, it saves as a text file. When I open the project in Eclipse, the file saves as a Java class, which was unusually odd.

- [Project Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkkel.png)
- [Package Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AICey.png)

Comment: While it is not the most helpful advice don't use IntelliJ. IntelliJ is prone to have random problems such as the one that your currently having. I would recommend sticking to eclipse, especially since it seems to work correctly in eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In intellij press `ctrl+alt+S` , it should open File Types settings

```
Settings -> Editor -> FileTypes
```

In the `Recognized File Types` go to option `Text` and check in `File Name Patterns`

if it has **User.java** or any other pattern that points that file names starting or contain ***user*** should map to txt file.
basically this is telling intelliJ that it needs to interpret the given patterns of file as .txt file.
**you can remove the patterns that are not required.**

you can check the image below. **hope it helps** :)

[image]